# What's the most accurate automated way to check the width of a website?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a script that analyzes websites. I'm looking to check the width. I understand, not all websites will be able to be checked automatically, but I'm trying to figure out a strategy that will work for most business websites. I'm working in PHP if you are wondering, however an explanation of a strategy might be sufficient without PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

Most websites have dynamic page widths so the width depends on the client's browser/screen width. There is therefore, more often than not, no "set width".

Comment: @user83039 Yes, responsive was the word I was looking for. As for how to proceed in doing what you would like to achieve, I think the best option would be looking at the page's CSS: if the page's width is a % value, then most likely it is a responsive web page; if it is a px value, then it is a static page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can use javascript to check the widht of the window on load.

```
(function($){ 
$(document).ready(function(){
var current_width = $(window).width();
}
```

Comment: Whoever down-voted this, can you tell me what is wrong with this proposed solution?